# How to compare comma separated values in mysql as exact match

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have table name called group and in which because of some reason I've comma separated values in field X now I want to compare an array with that field in mysql if array matches exact same then result should return.

For example :
I've a row

> 1 - a,b,c 2 - x,y,z

so if array contains :

```
array(b,a,c) // Return row 1 
array(z,x,y) // Return row 2 
array(a,b) // Return false
```

Comment: Fix the data so every query isn't nonsense

Answer (score -2):

You might use the `FIND_IN_SET` function. Something like the following would work for your case on requiring b,a,c:

```
select * from table where FIND_IN_SET("b", `column`) AND FIND_IN_SET("c", `column`) AND FIND_IN_SET("c", `column`);
```

Please see the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2abac/3/0)

Comment: what if all a b and c are in row but there's an d also then also this query works but it should not

Comment: `In` will check whether a value exists in the specified comma-delimited resultset

Comment: Because ... ? And please do not downvote without explanation or if you think it's wrong write your own answer. The `in` operator should work with a comma delimited column.

Comment: added a fiddle and used find-in-set

Comment: @MohitBumb did you find a solution? Would like to know whether you did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316366/mysql-returns-exact-word-match-from-text-content