# MySQL returns exact word match from text content

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to write a query which can compare words from string and returns exact match instead of like.

Lets say I've a field called txt which have value "Hello, I am string"

Now if I search for "am" then it should return that row if I search for "I" or "string" or "Hello," then it should return this row but if I search for "a", "tri" or "str" then it should not return anything

Comment: Use full text search:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: You can use MySql REGEXP, it already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is probably full text search.

However, there are two caveats.  If you have short strings, such as product descriptions or user comments, and want to use `like`, you can do something like this:

```
where concat(' ', txt, ' ') like concat('% ', $word, ' %')
```

However, this assumes that the delimiters are spaces. So, it would not find "Hello".  You can fix this by doing:

```
where concat(' ', replace(txt, ',' ' '), ' ') like concat('% ', $word, ' %')
```

But you'll quickly find that this is a pain.  Hence:  full text search.

Second, if you are really storing *keywords* in the column, then the solution is simpler.  Don't do that.  Create a junction table that has one row per original table row and one per keyword.  Storing lists in strings is a bad idea in SQL.

Comment: I'm trying it just 2 mins. I'll let you know and accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: not returning any records also not giving any errors

Comment: @MohitBumb . . . Perhaps there is a case sensitivity issue.  You can try to use `lower()` to put them in the same case.

Comment: it works, there's some minor issue but issue solved thanks